# How do I Check to See if a column is within latitiude/longitude coordinates?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have two columns latitude and longitude. I am trying to create boundaries such that only points within the boundary is returned. For example i have this static lat/long (40.6681, -73.9806).

There are latitude/longitude coordinates in my database which are not within that static coordinate, how do I only select those coordinates within 40.6681, -73.9806? Here is my query:

```
select houses from housing where borough = 'BROOKLYN' and latitude + longitude = st_within(40.6681, -73.9806);
```

The error message I see is:

Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: probably just a typo - you might want to check the longitude value - this needs to be around -74 for NY

Comment: Well i am trying to use park slope not the entire borough of brooklyn.

Comment: What Steven Kay is telling you is that if you want to be in the western hemisphere, your longitude should be is negative. 73.9806 is 73.9806 *East*. 73.9806W will be -73.9806

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the function properly. ST_WITHIN() takes two arguments both type geom.

For example:

```
ST_Within(geometry A, geometry B);
```

will return true if geometry A is completely inside geometry B.

You are going to want to try something like this:

```
select houses from housing where borough = 'BROOKLYN'
AND ST_WITHIN(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), YOUR_BOUNDARY_GEOM);
```

see postgis [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the response. So basically I can't have a static latlng, i need to turn 40.6681, 73.9806 into a geom correct?

Comment: Yes, you will have to convert it to a geom. Your boundary also need to be a geom.

Comment: That last point is critical, and it can't be a point (ST_Within for two points is never true). The boundary should be describing the extent of the are (e.g. borough) you are interested in, and the border won't match.